# Is it possible to parse this list of dictionaries more efficient and faster?

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, parsing, list-comprehension

I have a list full of dictionaries and lists with a deep hierarchy originating from a xml-file. I want to parse it and bring it into a new format in the most efficient and fastest way because I deal with a huge amount of data. I thought this would be some fun for you guys!

My code up to now is working. From that you can conclude where the relevant information in the original list is located. I won't show the original list here because it's too big and fuzzy. However, I can add that information if you need it.

```
analysis = []
for sentence in mylist:
    for i, word in enumerate(sentence['w']):
        tmp_dic = {}
        index = i+1
        tmp_dic['index'] = str(index)
        tmp_dic['text'] = word['t']
        tmp_dic['lemma'] = word['lemma']['@class']
        morph = ''
        if len(word['morphology']['morpheme']) > 1:
            for morphem in word['morphology']['morpheme']:
                morph += '[' + morphem['t'] + ']'
        else:
            morph += '[' + word['morphology']['morpheme']['t'] + ']'
        tmp_dic['morph'] = morph
        tmp_dic['pos'] = word['pos']['@class']
        tmp_dic['posprob'] = word['pos']['@confidence']
        if index == len(sentence['w']):
            tmp_dic['eos'] = True      
        analysis.append(tmp_dic)
```

I guess the code is quite self-explanatory. However, I'm wondering whether there exists more elegant and especially faster code using list comprehensions for instance. If you need some extra information, please feel free to ask! The final result should look like this:

```
>>>print(analysis)
[{'index': '1', 'text': 'zo', 'lemma': 'zo', 'morph': '[zo]', 'pos': 'BW()', 'posprob': '0.999512'}, {'index': '2', 'text': 'schrijft', 'lemma': 'schrijven', 'morph': '[schrijf][t]', 'pos': 'WW(pv,tgw,met-t)', 'posprob': '0.998984'}, {'index': '3', 'text': 'paulus', 'lemma': 'paulus', 'morph': '[paulus]', 'pos': 'ADJ(vrij,basis,zonder)', 'posprob': '0.382880'}, {'index': '4', 'text': 'in', 'lemma': 'in', 'morph': '[in]', 'pos': 'VZ(init)', 'posprob': '0.999350'}, {'index': '5', 'text': 'de', 'lemma': 'de', 'morph': '[de]', 'pos': 'LID(bep,stan,rest)', 'posprob': '0.999964'}, {'index': '6', 'text': 'brief', 'lemma': 'brief', 'morph': '[brief]', 'pos': 'N(soort,ev,basis,zijd,stan)', 'posprob': '0.999172'}, {'index': '7', 'text': 'aan', 'lemma': 'aan', 'morph': '[aan]', 'pos': 'VZ(init)', 'posprob': '0.999180'}, {'index': '8', 'text': 'de', 'lemma': 'de', 'morph': '[de]', 'pos': 'LID(bep,stan,rest)', 'posprob': '0.999964'}, {'index': '9', 'text': 'gemeente', 'lemma': 'gemeente', 'morph': '[gemeente]', 'pos': 'N(soort,ev,basis,zijd,stan)', 'posprob': '0.999756'}, {'index': '10', 'text': 'in', 'lemma': 'in', 'morph': '[in]', 'pos': 'VZ(init)', 'posprob': '0.931125'}, {'index': '11', 'text': 'filippi', 'lemma': 'filippi', 'morph': '[filippi]', 'pos': 'N(soort,ev,basis,onz,stan)', 'posprob': '0.508322', 'eos': True}, {'index': '1', 'text': 'zij', 'lemma': 'zij', 'morph': '[zij]', 'pos': 'VNW(pers,pron,nomin,vol,3p,mv)', 'posprob': '0.934959'}, {'index': '2', 'text': 'verzetten', 'lemma': 'verzetten', 'morph': '[ver][zet][en]', 'pos': 'WW(pv,tgw,mv)', 'posprob': '0.909747'}, {'index': '3', 'text': 'zich', 'lemma': 'zich', 'morph': '[zich]', 'pos': 'VNW(refl,pron,obl,red,3,getal)', 'posprob': '0.999740'}, {'index': '4', 'text': 'met', 'lemma': 'met', 'morph': '[met]', 'pos': 'VZ(init)', 'posprob': '0.999480'}, {'index': '5', 'text': 'hem', 'lemma': 'hem', 'morph': '[hem]', 'pos': 'VNW(pers,pron,obl,vol,3,ev,masc)', 'posprob': '0.992108'}, {'index': '6', 'text': 'tegen', 'lemma': 'tegen', 'morph': '[tegen]', 'pos': 'VZ(init)', 'posprob': '0.997583'}, {'index': '7', 'text': 'de', 'lemma': 'de', 'morph': '[de]', 'pos': 'LID(bep,stan,rest)', 'posprob': '0.999964'}, {'index': '8', 'text': 'theologie', 'lemma': 'theologie', 'morph': '[theologisch][ie]', 'pos': 'N(soort,ev,basis,zijd,stan)', 'posprob': '0.997691', 'eos': True}]
```

Comment: might be shorter if you use `lambda`.

Comment: @chepner ```analysis``` is a list which I define in the very first line and use later on to store the parsing results

Comment: Sorry, I misread that, and though `analysis` was a string you were parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't try turning this into a list comprehension, it would make it unnecessarily convoluted.

Instead you can do small improvements such as instantiating `tmp_dic` with values instead of assigning the keys after the fact, starting the enumeration from 1, instead of setting the index seperately, and using f strings to build up `morph` instead of appending strings.

```
analysis = []
for sentence in mylist:
    for i, word in enumerate(sentence['w'], 1):
        tmp_dic = {
            'index': str(i),
            'text': word['t'],
            'lemma': word['lemma']['@class'],
            'pos': word['pos']['@class'],
            'posprob': word['pos']['@confidence'],
            'morph': "[{inner_morph}]".format(
                inner_morph="][".join(morphem["t"] for morphem in word['morphology']['morpheme'])
             )
        }

        if i == len(sentence['w']):
            tmp_dic['eos'] = True      
        analysis.append(tmp_dic)
```

Comment: My implemenation takes: 0.0063 msec. This one takes: 0.00299 msec. (Tested on very small dataset) Nice! I also really like how it gets rid of the index = 1+i thing of my implementation

Comment: @hyhno01 - Thats good to hear, is it right that `morpheme` is only a list if it contains more than one element?, you could remove the if statement if its always a list, and you can remove the last if statement if you could have `eos` have a value of false

Comment: Unfortunately, ```morpheme``` is always the list. And yes, I could have a eos values of ```False```. However, I decided against it by which the output resembles more the output of another program which I firstly used for my analysis

Comment: @hyhno01 - I've updated to remove the `morpheme` if statement then which should also help, I'll roll back if this introduces an error since your else statement shouldn't work if it was a list